# Computational complexity of optimizing the difference between two concave functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I know the difference of two convex functions is called D.C. Program, see Horst R, Thoai N V. DC programming: overview[J]. Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications, 1999, 103(1): 1-43.

However, I am wondering what is the difference of two concave functions called? Is there any existing results for this problem? Specifically, I have $f(x) = g(x) - h(x): \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are concave functions. What will be the computational complexity if I want to minimize/maximize $f(x)$? Intuitively, it's NP-Hard because either maximizing a convex and minimizing a concave function is NP-Hard in general, is it true for $\underset{x}{\text{min/max }} f(x)$

Comment: Note that $f(x) = g(x) - h(x) = (-h(x)) - (-g(x))$, and that $-h$ and $-g$ are convex functions. Therefore, $f$ is a difference of convex functions

Comment: As noted by madnessweasley, minimizing or maximizing the difference of two concave functions is exactly equivalent to minimizing the difference of two convex functions.  Is there more to your question?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I think my question is about the computational complexity of this problem. Is there any existing result about the computational complexity of optimizing the D.C. problem? I tried to search on Google Scholar but didn't find any. Is this problem NP-Hard?

Comment: Nonconvex quadratic programming is NP-Hard.  A nonconvex QP can be formulated as a DC problem.  Thus solving the DC problem is NP-Hard.